# Which version of spring boot has @WebIntegrationTest included, it shows red in Intellij at the time of adding it

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, mockito, dependency-management

I have Spring Boot test dependency added in Gradle file as

```json
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
ext['mockito.version'] = '2.7.5'
```

Still not able to use `@WebIntegrationTest`, it shows red color if I try to add in Intellij. What should I have in my application so that I would be able to test REST API with `@WebIntegrationTest`?

I'm able to test it with different method but just not able to get why it is failing

Comment: Are you using springboot version lower than `1.2.1`?

Comment: No version is defined against whatever added for "org.springframework.boot" in gradle file, So I thought it would be getting the latest version at the time of build isn't it?

Comment: not sure about gradle builds. You can check the versions by checking the downloaded dependencies.

Comment: Yes then its 1.5.1.RELEASE

Comment: Can you try 1.4.2 version of springboot ? Meanwhile, I'll find out why it is missing in 1.5.1 version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Still not able to use @WebIntegrationTest, it shows red color if I try
>   to add in intellij.

As said by you that you have springboot 1.5.1 version, `WebIntegrationTest` class was deprecated from 1.4 in favor of `SpringBootTest`.

Below is the javadocs supporting above.

> - @since 1.2.1  * @see IntegrationTest  * @deprecated as of 1.4 in favor of  * {@link
>     org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest} with  * {@code
>     webEnvironment=RANDOM_PORT} or {@code webEnvironment=DEFINED_PORT}. 
>     */ @Documented @Inherited @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
>     @BootstrapWith(WebAppIntegrationTestContextBootstrapper.class)
>     @Deprecated public @interface WebIntegrationTest {

You have two choices here,

1. Ditch `WebIntegrationTest` class and start using `SpringBootTest`
2. Downgrade springboot version lower to 1.4.0 and use `WebIntegrationTest`(not recommended)

Here is the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4.0-M2-Release-Notes) of 1.4.0-M2 release notes explaining about the deprecation of `WebIntegrationTest`

Hope this helps!

Comment: `@WebIntegrationTest` was not deprecated, it was *removed* in version 1.5. (I long the old days when backward compatibility was a principle and not just a possibility.)

Answer (score 1):

These deprecated annotations

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(BootApplication::class))
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=8081")
```

in Spring Boot 1.5+ are equivalent to

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(BootApplication::class), properties = arrayOf("server.port=8081"))
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

From the

```
org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest
```

javadoc (emphasis mine)

> This annotation can be used as an alternative to @IntegrationTest and @WebAppConfiguration.
>   **Since:1.2.1**

Comment: Thanks, but I have version 1.5.1 still its not able to get it, I don't know why